# What does a javascript regular expression's exec() function actually return?

Tags: javascript, regex

Simply out of interest - what actually is it?

When I `console.log` it (assuming there's a match) I get something that looks like it's halfway between a plain object and an array:

```
 [ 'abc', undefined, index: 0, input: 'abcdef' ]
```

Comment: A regular expression doesn't "return" anything - it's not a function. What function were you calling?

Comment: @Sacho - .exec() - updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about the result of `console.log('abcdef'.match(/abc/))`.

**[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** returns an **array** containing the matched results or **null** if there were no matches.

If you change `console.log` to `console.dir`, you will see it's an array (which add a `input` property to the array, **remember that an array in javascript is also an object**, which you could add property to it).

[image]

Comment: WTH are you linking a chinese documentation? Please point to English ressources only, or translate them if necessary.

Comment: @Bergi Changed to english version :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an Array with some values. However, it contains strings and some key value pairs. (I'm not sure what regex function you are using.)

```
[ 'abc', undefined, index: 0, input: 'abcdef' ]
```

Below is the example on regex..when there are more than one item in the string matches the given pattern, then it returns an array with all the items.

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/ain/g);

[ain,ain,ain]
```